# three column composite key and hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g

I have 3 tables:

```
Table A(Col1,Col2,Col3) -- Col1 Primary Key
Table B(Col4,Col5,Col6) -- (Col4,Col5) --Composite Key
Table C(Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10) --(Col7,Col8,Col9) -- Composite key References (Col1,Col4,Col5)
```

How `hibernate` mapping is done for this table C?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just make composite key that have composite key inside it?

Something like this:

```
<composite-id name="id" class="com.domain.CompositeTableC">
    <key-property name="col1" type="string">
        <column name="Col1" length="8" />
    </key-property>
    <key-property name="col4" type="string">
        <column name="Col4" length="8" />
    </key-property>
    <key-property name="col5" type="string">
        <column name="Col5" length="8"/>
    </key-property>
</composite-id>
```

And the class :

```
public class CompositeTableC{
//constructors
private String col1;
private CompositeTableB compositeB;
//getters and setters
}

public class CompositeTableB {
//constructors
private String col4;
private String col5;
//getters and setters
}
```